# Remove a substring from a bash variable

Tags: bash

A bash variable contents are command line arguments, like this:

```
args="file-1.txt file-2.txt -k file-3.txt -k --some-argument-1 --some-argument-2"
```

the string `-k` can appear anywhere in the above string, there are some other arguments that are not `-k`.

Is it possible to extract all the strings (i.e. file names with all other arguments) except `-k` from the argument, and assign it to a bash variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `sed`

> Is is possible to extract all the strings (i.e. file names with all other arguments) except -k from the argument, and assign it to a bash variable?

I am taking that to mean that you want to remove `-k` while keeping everything else.  If that is the case:

```
$ new=$(echo " $args " | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]-k[[:space:]]/ /g')
$ echo $new
file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt --some-argument-1 --some-argument-2
```

#### Using only bash

This question is tagged with bash.  Under bash, the use of sed is unnecessary:

```
$ new=" $args "
$ new=${new// -k / }
$ echo $new
file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt --some-argument-1 --some-argument-2
```

Comment: thanks, but when the argument list starts or ends with `-k`, this does not work.

Comment: @ramgorur I just added a quick fix for that.  Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Piping it to `sed` should work:

```
echo $args | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\-[[:alnum:]\-]*//g'
file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt
```

and you can assign it to a variable with:

```
newvar=`echo $args | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\-[[:alnum:]\-]*//g'`
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for not pointing out the outlier cases, there is a small subtlety, the question is updated. thanks!

Comment: but it does not work when the argument list begins with `-k`, I am novice at sed.

Answer (score 1):

Command-line arguments in `bash` should be stored in an array, to allow for arguments that contain characters that need to be quoted.

```
args=(file-1.txt file-2.txt -k file-3.txt -k --some-argument-1 --some-argument-2)
```

To extract strings other than `-k`, just use a for loop to filter them.

```
newargs=()
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    [[ $arg = "-k" ]] && newargs+=("$arg")
done
```